# Error in Linq query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to collect a value from a domain object through EF linq query. But I am getting an error pls can some help me correct this.

```
public String[] ReturnPatientIDs(int CounsellingRoomID)
{

    var messageObject = this.context.CounsellingMessages.Where(c => c.CounsellingRoomID == CounsellingRoomID).Distinct();

    String[] PatientIDs = new String[messageObject.Count()];

    for (int k = 0; k < PatientIDs.Length; k++)
    {
        PatientIDs[k] = messageObject.ElementAt(k).Chatname;
    }

    return PatientIDs;
}
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Me.Domain.General.CounsellingMessage ElementAt[CounsellingMessage](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Me.Domain.General.CounsellingMessage], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'MedicalApp.Domain.General.CounsellingMessage ElementAt[CounsellingMessage](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MedicalApp.Domain.General.CounsellingMessage], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 43:             for (int k = 0; k < PatientIDs.Length; k++ )
> Line 44:             {
> Line 45:                 PatientIDs[k] = messageObject.ElementAt(k).Chatname;
> Line 46:             }
> Line 47:
> ```

Comment: Try to replace this PatientIDs[k] = messageObject.ElementAt(k).Chatname; to this PatientIDs[k] = messageObject.ToList()[k].Chatname;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ElementAt` method isn't supported. The `messageObject` query isn't executed till you call `Count()` and `ElementAt()` on it, and those are being treated as LINQ to Entity queries.

The action taken in the `for` loop can be rolled into your LINQ query by adding a `Select` statement:

```
public String[] ReturnPatientIDs(int CounsellingRoomID)
{
    var query = this.context.CounsellingMessages
                    .Where(c => c.CounsellingRoomID == CounsellingRoomID)
                    .Select(c => c.Chatname)
                    .Distinct();

    return query.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Putting `Select` before `Distinct` can change results (on original code `Distinct` is done on whole objects, no on one property as in yours). Although I think your query is something author is really looking for.

Comment: Thanks to you all Grateful. Thanks @Ahmad